# confirm email form type?

Tags: forms, emails

There is a [confirm password](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#password_confirm) form type.  I don't suppose there is a confirm email address form type available?  Possibly as a contributed module?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)

You will get a screen like this in example.com/admin/config/system/logintoboggan
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any module for this - it's not a part of Drupal core, but it would be relatively simple to create the repeat functionality yourself. Simply add the repeat form field and a validation check that the two values are the same.